# Opal ruby (opal-build) to transform nwn-lib (nwn-gff) to javascript? Lost

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

I'm trying to familiarize myself with both ruby and javascript through a hobby project to create a conversation editor (perhaps a google drive app) that shares i/o formats compatible with Neverwinter Nights (ergo https://github.com/niv/nwn-lib). I thought I'd take a look at Opalrb to see if it could translate those nwn tools into a form I could use or examine; but I can't seem to get the opal-build command to produce anything but errors attempting to convert gff.rb.

I don't know if I'm making a simple syntactic error entering options or have a deeper, flawed understanding of the process (probably both). I'm confident I've installed the gems and used nwn-gff successfully. That's about it.

My question(s) then: what specific steps must I take to accomplish this conversion with Opal? What options do I have to utilize these tools, considering my ultimate platform?

(link to nwn gff file format: http://social.bioware.com/bw_projects_file_download.php?project_file_id=10782)

Cheers and thanks

Comment: I'd like to know the opal version and the exact build command with the relative error before attempting to answer, also feel free to [open an issue for the error](https://github.com/opal/opal/issues/new)

Comment: opal-0.6.2. I've gotten results. "opal-build -g nwn-lib gff" returns "Could not find asset: gff." gff.rb is located: */nwn-lib/lib/nwn/ (as installed by gem install). If I move gff.rb up to lib/, the command works. Before that, it was a matter of discerning the options and example in -h. -g and -r both read "E.g.: opal-build --require opal-browser browser Will build browser.rb from the Opal gem opal-browser", yet -r nwn-lib gff "cannot load such file -- nwn-lib". (I've yet to successfully install, or build, opal-browser gem for that matter, from any repository or locally.) The errors are mine.

Comment: I fixed that stuff on master and we're about to release 0.7, so my first advice is to try with opal from master (git clone …; bundle; rake install). If you just want to build opal-browser you can also try to copy the "dist" rake task from here: https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/0-6-stable/Rakefile#L22-L31

Answer (score 0):

Opal v0.7 has been released, the CLI now features a `-g` option to which the name of a gem can be passed and a `-c` to compile to standard output.

E.g.

```
opal -g nwn-lib -e 'require "nwn/gff"' -c > gff.js
```